# Pick a non-zero value reduce repetitive

Tags: sql, firebird

I have the following table

| Text | Num1 | Num2 | Num3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Test2 | 4 | 2 | 1 |
| Test3 | 7 | 1 | 8 |

I need to get 2 differences

- Num1 and Num2
- Num1 and Num3

I only care if the first difference is negative and the second difference is positive.

So I do the following

- `MINVALUE(Num1 - Num2, 0)`
- `MAXVALUE(Num1 - Num3, 0)`

Further I want a field where either the difference 1 or 2, whichever is not 0.

| Text | Num1 | Num2 | Num3 | MINVALUE(Num1 - Num2, 0) | MAXVALUE(Num1 - Num3, 0) | DIFF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | -1 | 0 | -1 |
| Test2 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 3 | 3 |
| Test3 | 7 | 1 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I can't seem to find a short way to find the `DIFF` column and end up with repetitive code, currently I am using

```
case MINVALUE(Num1 - Num2, 0)
when 0 then maxvalue(num1 - num3, 0)
else MINVALUE(Num1 - Num2, 0)
end
```

Is there a way to reduce this?

Here a dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/2OpPzJYU

**Note:**

The actual calculation is more complex than `NUM1 - NUM2`.

Including string manipulation, date diffs, date adds, cases and stuff, and I am afraid that because of the repetitive code it will perform worse, than if I would only calculate it once.

I couldn't find an answer if Firebird would optimize repetitive code or not, so if it does only calculate the `case` and the `else` block once and not twice, I would already be happy with the solution at hand.

In the end I have three states, a negative value, a positive value and 0, it should prefer either negative or positive over 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a derived table:

```sql
select 
  difference1,
  difference2,
  case
    when difference1 = 0 then difference2
    else difference1
  end as difference3
from (
  select
    minvalue(num1 - num2, 0) as difference1,
    maxvalue(num1 - num3, 0) as difference2
  from SourceData
) t
```

dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/2KaFKMLg

You can also consider a cross join with a [lateral derived table](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-dml-select-joins-lateral) (though for this example, it will just make it more complex):

```sql
select t.difference1, t.difference2, a.difference3
from (
  select
    minvalue(num1 - num2, 0) as difference1,
    maxvalue(num1 - num3, 0) as difference2
  from SourceData
) t,
lateral (
  select case
    when t.difference1 = 0 then t.difference2
    else t.difference1
  end as difference3
  from rdb$database
) a
```

dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/6W-Bv_G6

Other alternatives as mentioned in the comments:

- Using [`DECODE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-scalarfuncs-decode):

  ```sql
  decode(difference1, 0, difference2, difference1) as difference3
  ```

  This is basically equivalent to a "simple CASE"
- Using [`IIF`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-scalarfuncs-iif):

  ```sql
  iif(difference1 = 0, difference2, difference1) as difference3
  ```

  This is equivalent to a "searched CASE" with one `WHEN` and an `ELSE`
- Using [`COALESCE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-scalarfuncs-coalesce) and [`NULLIF`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-scalarfuncs-nullif):

  ```sql
  coalesce(nullif(difference1, 0), difference2) as difference3
  ```

  I think this might be hard to understand or confusing (especially if you have to evaluate more than two expressions).
- Write a custom PSQL function (either for the calculation as a whole, or to select the appropriate value to return)

An example dbfiddle for these (except the last option): https://dbfiddle.uk/F6Y4SKWo

Comment: Should have known better, and said that this isn’t an option. My SQL is generated by defining a custom xml file, and my xml/sql generation can’t do derived tables. Do you maybe have a different idea? and maybe can you weigh in on the does firebird optimize the query if the same calculation is declared multiple times in the query? (sorry for the many typos in question)

Comment: @RandRandom Can your XML/SQL generation handle lateral joins? In any case, as far as I'm aware, expression evaluation in Firebird is not optimized to treat multiple occurrences of the same expression as a single expression, but as far as I know in a CASE it will only evaluate the expression that is used.

Comment: Never mind, lateral joins wouldn't make sense, because they would still require derived tables.

Comment: @RandRandom What about Common Table Expressions?

Comment: I am afraid to say neither (cte, later joins), current version is simple select, and I can define fields as I want but there isn’t a way to re-structure the select it self. So I hoped, there was a function I was missing `IIFVALUE(condition, value1, [valuex], defaultvalue)` where the array of values is validated against the condition and if true it will return it. if none is true, it will use default value.

Comment: You can use [`DECODE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-scalarfuncs-decode), but that is basically just an alternative for a simple case. There is also [`IIF`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-scalarfuncs-iif), but again, that is not much different from a searched case with a single `WHEN` and an `ELSE`.

Comment: @RandRandom Maybe you can do something complex with [`NULLIF`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-scalarfuncs-nullif) and [`COALESCE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-scalarfuncs-coalesce), but I wouldn't recommend that (I'm thinking of something like `coalesce(nullif(<expression1>, 0), <expression2>)`. Maybe you could write a custom PSQL function?

Comment: PSQL function is plan b. May I ask why you wouldn’t recommend it? It’s looking good for me.

Comment: @RandRandom In this case it looks quite OK, but it might be hard to understand (it is not really self-explanatory in my opinion), especially if you need more than those 2 expressions.